# Unspupported operand types

Tags: python

I am preparing for my first computer science exam and I a trying to right code that will increase the ord value of every character in a string and i keep getting unsupoorted operand types i'm not sure how too proceed.

```
message = input("Please enter a message :  ")



st = 0
num = int(input("please enter a number:  "))

for i in message:

    st = message[i-1]
    total += ord(st)
    total = total + num
    hello = chr(total)
    print(hello,end= "")
    ordinal = chr(ord(message)+3)

print(ordinal)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhOSm.png)

Comment: Code is text; put a [mcve] **in the question itself**. Presumably the problem is with `message[i-1]` - when you iterate over a string *you get the characters*, not the indices, `i` is already the character you want.

Comment: Paste your code here.  Don't link to an image.  Those aren't searchable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i'm not familiar with indices this is my first semester coding, and yes that line is my issue and i'm not sure how to solve it because i keep getting that errror

Comment: You don't have to be familiar with indices, *you don't need to use them at all!* Try this: `for i in message: print(i)`. You should immediately see the problem.

Comment: @Daniel the st isn't `message[i-1]` it's just `i` so you would do `st = i`. Your code has many more problems than just that though. `i` is the actual character

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i get another error with ord again on line 11 saying it expected a string with length 1 but int was found

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mcve] - the shortest possible code to give that error message, and the complete error traceback.

Comment: `''.join([chr(ord(i)+1) for i in raw_input('Enter your string :')])` This will help you to increase ord value of each character by 1.

Comment: @RahulKP, i tried that but it's just printing the exact same letters out each on a single line amd they are still the same sorry if i appear ignorant just this question really confuses me

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of problems here

#### Looping through characters incorrectly.

```
for i in message:
    st = message[i-1]
```

Look's like you're trying to get the character at position i, this is wrong. you're variable `i` is already that character. Rename it so something more clear.

```
for character in message:
```

#### Calculating the total for the character

You're code is like

```
total += ord(character)
```

This is adding the ord to a variable that doesn't exist. You  should do something like this

```
for character in message:
    currentOrd = ord(character)
    newOrd = currentOrd + num
```

#### Getting the new character

```
hello = chr(total)
```

This is a horribly named variable, you should use something like this:

```
for character in message:
    currentOrd = ord(character)
    newOrd = currentOrd + num
    newChar = chr(newOrd)
```

#### Printing the word.

```
print(hello,end= "")
```

This is an awkward hack. You should just build up a string as you go along. Something like this

```
finalString = ""
for character in message:
    currentOrd = ord(character)
    newOrd = currentOrd + num
    newChar = chr(newOrd)
    finalString += newOrd
```

#### The last line

```
ordinal = chr(ord(message)+3)
```

This line does nothing, it creates a variable that is immediately thrown away, just remove this line

#### The final code

```
message = input("Please enter a message :  ")
num = int(input("please enter a number:  "))
newWord = ""
for character in message:
    currentOrd = ord(character)
    newOrd = currentOrd + num
    newChar = chr(newOrd)
    newWord += newChar

print(newWord)
```

As you can see by running, it clearly works

```
Please enter a message :  This code actually works now
please enter a number:  2
Vjku"eqfg"cevwcnn{"yqtmu"pqy
```

#### Better final code

This code does the exact same using a generator, you probably shouldn't use this on your test, but just showing you that this is another way to do it.

```
message = input("Please enter a message :  ")
num = int(input("please enter a number:  "))
print("".join(chr(ord(char)+num) for char in message))
```

#### Checking if alphabetical character (as specified in comments)

You can use `if character.isalpha():` to determine is a character is alphabetical. Code would look like this:

```
message = input("Please enter a message :  ")
num = int(input("please enter a number:  "))
newWord = ""
for character in message:
    currentOrd = ord(character)
    newOrd = currentOrd + num
    newChar = chr(newOrd)

    if character.isalpha():
        newWord += newChar

print(newWord)
```

Comment: thank you all i have to do now is to add limitations our professor wanted to make sure the only alphabetical characters were printed

Comment: @Daniel Use `if character.isalpha()` to check if it's an alpha character before adding it to `newWord`

Comment: you have be so helpful thank you where would you say was my thinking incorrect in trying to solve the problem?

Comment: @Daniel Mostly that you thought `i` was an index value for the character in the string when it was actually the character itself. Then just generally using variables together

Comment: so basically i should just create more meaningful variables that are easier to follow?

Comment: i tried my own method to make sure that the ord value are in a specific range would it be okay if i showed it to you?